# WCFTestClient gives Error message by disabling TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, ssl

We have disabled TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1 in our server as a security concern and enabled TLS 1.2
When ever we invoke the WCF Webservice using WCFTestClient we are getting below error message.
I tried so many ways to fix but nothing works (refer:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-security-via-appcontext-switches)

I found one article its problem with WCFTestClient but not sure .
(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/wcf-test-client-does-not-support-tls-12/1193549)
Can anyone help on this

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://devseatm07.europe.shell.com/EventCollectorService/v3.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP     request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Server stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

   Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage 
   retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IEventCollectorService.ReceiveEvent(EventMessage eventMessage)
   at EventCollectorServiceClient.ReceiveEvent(EventMessage eventMessage)

   Inner Exception:
   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at 
 
 
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

   Inner Exception:
   The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, X509Certificate2 selectedCert, Flags flags)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

Comment: You may have to force it to use 1.2: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 3):

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess
> a common algorithm

This error is caused by a mismatch in the cipher algorithm because the TLS 1.2 protocol was not used before calling the API or service.
You can setup the SecurityProtocol variable.
The first thing you have to do is to add the following line of code within your ASP.NET project:

```
//Add TLS 1.2 to the supported cryptographic protocols
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

If your .NET Framework version is 4.5 or below, or in case you don’t have the “Tls12” typed value, just use the int value instead, which is 3072:

```
// Add TLS 1.2 to the supported cryptographic protocols (for .NET Framework < 4.5)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

The best spot to insert this line would be the Application_Start() method in your Global.asax (ASP.NET 4.x) or Startup.cs (ASP.NET 5 / .NET Core) file.
You can also try other solutions:https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-client-server-cannot-comunicate-because-they-possess-common-algorithm-how-to-fix-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1):

After a long stretch finally I identified the fix. Below script helped me to invoke the service using WCFTestClient.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 
'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

Answer (score 1):

definitely solve this problem

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // .NET 4.5
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; // .NET 4.0
```